# Working With SQL Server Developer Edition

Tags: sql-server-2005, development-environment

I just bought Visual Studio 2008 Professional and it came with SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition.  I'm used to using SQL Server 2005 at work, but the Developer edition doesn't seem to come with Server Management Studio, so I'm at a bit of a loss.  A few questions:

1. What resources are there for configuring and setting up SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition?
2. What are some resources for managing databases (I know that I can have Multiple Databases with SQL Server 2005), and what 'extras' are provided by Developer Edition?
3. Are there any funky things I need to know about if I were to create a database and move it from Developer Edition to an actual deployment server?
4. Are there any other 'gotchas'?

---

Edit: I've answered the 'Why isn't SQL Server Management Studio showing up' question below.  Resources for the other questions are still appreciated.

Any other insights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, If you actually have the full Developer edition on SQL2005 it does have SSMS with it, you just didnt choose that option in the install.

What is more likely is that you installed SQL 2005 Express Edition which does not include SSMS

(SSMS = SQL Server Management Studio)

To manage your SQL instance you should download SQL Server Management Studio Express from here
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en

keep in mind that Express installs with an instance name so your server will actually be MACHINENAME\SqlExpress by default.

And SQLExpress databases are exactly the same as regular SQL Server - the db engine just has limitations when you are running Express.

Good luck.

Comment: I already had SQL 2005 Express installed. I chose the option to install Developer edition.  I didn't see an option to install Server Management Studio.

Comment: do an add/remove programs on the developer edition and see if you have an option for Client Tools or something like that

Comment: I posted the answer to the first question below.  If you've got insight on the others, please share. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It does come with SSMS and BIDS but it may not install them by default.  Re-run the installer and make sure the 'workstation' (IIRC) bits are installed.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that installing SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition on a system that also has the Express Edition requires that the user run the setup from the commandline like so:

`D:\SQL Server x86\Servers\setup.exe -SKUUPGRADE=1`

The other questions are still open to be answered, however.

Comment: When I read your question, I was prepared to write this very answer. I had this problem last week. Of course, the SQL Server installer does suggest you do this....

Comment: Yes, I had glossed over that when I installed it the first time. When I re-installed it last night, I realized that maybe there was something behind that warning box.

Answer (score 2):

Developer Edition contains all the features that Enterprise has (or at least most of them). This can be bad if you do not realise.

Some predecessors of mine finished a nice project that required the use of partitioned tables to greatly speed up our creaking DB. It worked a charm. A couple of weeks before deployment it got pointed out that only the Enterprise edition supported partitioned tables. They had to go cap-in-hand to the CFO and the CEO asking for about £16,000 in additional licencing costs.